# Passing data to server using JSON in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass some data which is stored in Javascript array to the server for database processings. I'm using codeignier.

Javascript Array (unitdata_set):-

```
[{"unit_id":"13","unit_title":"Testsdsdf","unit_max_occupancy":"3","unit_no":"1","unit_no_adults":"1","unit_no_children":"1","unit_no_extrabed":0,"unit_mealtype":"Full Board","unit_fullboard_adult":"6000.00","unit_fullboard_child":"4000.00","unit_halfboard_adult":"1800.00","unit_halfboard_child":"1200.00","room_total":"81600.00","all_room_price":"81600.00","extra_bed_price":"4.00","meal_price":22000,"saving_amount":16320,"discounted_bedroom_price":65280},{"unit_id":"14","unit_title":"Res2","unit_max_occupancy":"12","unit_no":"0","unit_no_adults":"0","unit_no_children":"0","unit_no_extrabed":0,"unit_mealtype":"Bed and Breakfast","unit_fullboard_adult":"9000.00","unit_fullboard_child":"7000.00","unit_halfboard_adult":"7000.00","unit_halfboard_child":"5000.00","room_total":"86400.00","all_room_price":"0.00","extra_bed_price":"","meal_price":0,"saving_amount":0,"discounted_bedroom_price":0}]
```

Ajax Function:-

```
  function sendBooking(){

          var boooking_url = "<?php echo site_url('tempbooking/addBooking'); ?>";
          var data_booking = '';
          data_booking = JSON.stringify(unitdata_set);

          $.post(boooking_url,{

            'booking_data[]':data_booking

          },function(data){
            console.log(data);

          });

      }
```

My Controller function which is used to receive the json data:-

```
function addBooking(){
            $booking_data=$this->input->post('booking_data');

             foreach ($booking_data as $booking) {

                             $booking_attr = json_decode($booking);
                        echo $booking_attr->unit_id . " " . $booking_attr->unit_title;
                        //echo $booking_attr['unit_id'] . " " . $booking_attr['unit_title'];
                }


        }
```

The error message that i get:-

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Trying to get property of non-object</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/tempbooking.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 156</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Trying to get property of non-object</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/tempbooking.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 156</p>

</div>
```

Print_r :-

```
print_r($this->input->post('booking_data'));

Array
(
    [0] => [{"unit_id":"13","unit_title":"Testsdsdf","unit_max_occupancy":"3","unit_no":"1","unit_no_adults":"1","unit_no_children":"1","unit_no_extrabed":0,"unit_mealtype":"Full Board","unit_fullboard_adult":"6000.00","unit_fullboard_child":"4000.00","unit_halfboard_adult":"1800.00","unit_halfboard_child":"1200.00","room_total":"81600.00","all_room_price":"81600.00","extra_bed_price":"4.00","meal_price":22000,"saving_amount":16320,"discounted_bedroom_price":65280},{"unit_id":"14","unit_title":"Res2","unit_max_occupancy":"12","unit_no":"0","unit_no_adults":"0","unit_no_children":"0","unit_no_extrabed":0,"unit_mealtype":"Bed and Breakfast","unit_fullboard_adult":"9000.00","unit_fullboard_child":"7000.00","unit_halfboard_adult":"7000.00","unit_halfboard_child":"5000.00","room_total":"86400.00","all_room_price":"0.00","extra_bed_price":"","meal_price":0,"saving_amount":0,"discounted_bedroom_price":0}]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because your JSON object is in an array ?

```
[ {JSON} ]
```

Try to modify your php function so you access the JSON in your array:

```
function addBooking(){
    $booking_data=$this->input->post('booking_data');

    foreach ($booking_data as $booking) {
        //NEW:
        $booking_attr = json_decode($booking[0]);

        echo $booking_attr->unit_id . " " . $booking_attr->unit_title;
    }
}
```

Comment: unable to do that since i'm using Array to push the data values. `unitdata_set.push({unit_id:test.resunit_details[i].ReservationUnitID, 
                          unit_title:test.resunit_details[i].ResUnitTitle,  
                          unit_max_occupancy:test.resunit_details[i].MaxOccupancy, 
                          unit_no:0, unit_no_adults:0, unit_no_adults:0, unit_no_children:0 });`

Comment: this still gives me the error. `Message:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: The problem is I'm passing objects as an array. the reason json_decode does not read is it is an array and not object. Although i tried using `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your controller

```
function addBooking()
{
    $booking_data=json_decode($this->input->post('booking_data'));
    foreach ($booking_data as $booking) 
    {   
        $booking_attr = ($booking);
        echo $booking_attr->unit_id . " " . $booking_attr->unit_title;
        //echo $booking_attr['unit_id'] . " " . $booking_attr['unit_title'];
    }
}
```

And change your javascript code like this

```
function sendBooking()
{
      var boooking_url = "<?php echo site_url('tempbooking/addBooking'); ?>";
      var data_booking = '';
      data_booking = (unitdata_set);

      $.post(boooking_url,{

        'booking_data':data_booking

      },function(data){
        console.log(data);

      });

  }
```

Comment: still not working. I'm getting this error. `<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/tempbooking.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 152</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/tempbooking.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 154</p>

</div> `

Comment: print out the $this->input->post('booking_data') at the begging of your controller function.

Comment: `[{"unit_id":"13","unit_title":"Testsdsdf","unit_max_occupancy":"3","unit_no":"1","unit_no_adults":"1","unit_no_children":"1","unit_no_extrabed":0,"unit_mealtype":"Half Board","unit_fullboard_adult":"6000.00","unit_fullboard_child":"4000.00","unit_halfboard_adult":"1800.00","unit_halfboard_child":"1200.00","room_total":"81600.00","all_room_price":"81600.00","extra_bed_price":"4.00","meal_price":6600,"saving_amount":16320,"discounted_bedroom_price":65280},`

Comment: `{"unit_id":"14","unit_title":"Res2","unit_max_occupancy":"12","unit_no":"0","unit_no_adults":"0","unit_no_children":"0","unit_no_extrabed":0,"unit_mealtype":"Bed and Breakfast","unit_fullboard_adult":"9000.00","unit_fullboard_child":"7000.00","unit_halfboard_adult":"7000.00","unit_halfboard_child":"5000.00","room_total":"90000.00","all_room_price":"0.00","extra_bed_price":"","meal_price":0,"saving_amount":0,"discounted_bedroom_price":0}] `

Comment: Please note i'm trying to pass Javascript Array that holds objects.

Comment: The output you prints its not array.Its json string.I have tested the code and working.please write down the javascript array `unitdata_set` that you wrote at your javascript so that I can edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason json_decode does not decode arrays which contains objects. If you are using javascript array to pass it to server-side / php please add your array to an object first. Follow below steps to get this done.

1. Please add your array to an object. As follows:-

   ```
   var unitdata_set = [];

   var obj_userbooking_data = {"bookings":unitdata_set}; //Added the above array into a new object and passed it to the server
   ```
2. Make sure to JSON.stringify the object.

   data_booking = JSON.stringify(obj_userbooking_data);

So the function becomes

```
function sendBooking(){


                    var boooking_url = "<?php echo site_url('booking/addBooking'); ?>";
                    var data_booking = '';
                    data_booking = JSON.stringify(obj_userbooking_data);

                    $.post(boooking_url,{

                      'booking_data':data_booking

                    },function(data){
                          console.log(data);

                    });



              }
```

3. use json_decode to decode the object which is converted into JSON string, using JSON.stringify in the client side. Thus, your server-side / php / Codeigniter Controller function becomes:-

   ```
       function addBooking(){
            $booking_data=$this->input->post('booking_data');
            $booking_data=json_decode($booking_data,true); 
            echo 'Your Data: ' . $booking_data[0]['unit_id'];
    }
   ```