# CodeIgniter and JSON objects: how to push my data to database?

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

I have a JS file that manages my data (push the data in my JSON objects, etc), and the classic MVC structure of files from CodeIgniter.

My JS contains my JSON objects that I would like to push in my database. How could I do for it? How can I reach the controller and the model from my JS file? I just can't figure out what is the right process to achieve my goal! And I find nothing similar to my question.

**EDIT** 
The data to push into the database is a part of the entire JSON object.The data to push is, for example: `{ "index": 0, "x": 50, "y": 80, "weight": 2, "px": 50, "py": 80, "fixed": 0 }`
In my JS file, I have tried this code:

```
  $("#hexa-btn").on("click", function () {

    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/prototype/returndata", 
         data: JSONshapes.shapes[0].nodes[0],
         cache: false,
         success:  
            function(data){
              console.log(data.index);
              console.log(data.x);
              console.log(data.y);
            }
          });
  });
```

And my controller has this function:

```
   function returndata(){
     $index = $this->input->post('index');  
     $x = $this->input->post('x'); 
     $y = $this->input->post('y'); 
     $weight = $this->input->post('weight'); 
     $px = $this->input->post('px'); 
     $py = $this->input->post('py'); 
     $fixed = $this->input->post('fixed'); ;  

     echo json_encode(array('node'=>$node));
   }
```

I am not sure at all about this function. It seems this is the role of the model to do this job, isn'it?

**2nd EDIT** So, I tried the solution of @Harish Lalwani, but this time with my array of nodes (not only one). I have the following function in the JavaScript file:

```
function sendNode(){
    var node_url = "/prototype/insert_node";
    var data_node = JSON.stringify(JSONshapes.shapes[0].nodes);
    $.post(node_url, {'node_data': data_node}, function(data){
      console.log(data.index);
    });
  }
```

and the following one in the controller (thank to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324121/passing-data-to-server-using-json-in-codeigniter?rq=1)):

```
    function insert_node(){
      $node_data = $this->input->post('node_data');
      $node_data = json_decode($node_data,true); 
      echo 'Your Data: ' . $node_data[0]['index'];
    },
```

But, when printing the data, I get `undefined`. The variable `data_node` is the following (so, is an array):

```
[{"index":0,"x":50,"y":80,"weight":2,"px":50,"py":80,"fixed":0},{"index":1,"x":189,"y":107,"weight":2,"px":189,"py":107},{"index":2,"x":95,"y":145,"weight":2,"px":95,"py":145}]
```

Now, I don't know anymore what to do! I find really too few examples. Can anyone put me out of my misery? Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: show your code, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax can solve your problem!

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "test.php", 
         data: yourData,
         dataType: "text",  
         cache:false,
         success: 
              function(data){
                alert(data);  //as a debugging message.
              }
          });// you have m
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried your solution, but I only get "undefined" results for the moment. I continue to try.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger this from your Js file. (include jQuery Library)

provide url, post key and value you will receive post parameters at specified URL.

```
       jQuery.post("<URL>", {dataname: datavalue}, function( r ) {
               console.log(r);
           });
```

I am also using ajax.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I don't know this method, but I will search and read information about it.

Answer (score 0):

From your Original Post, I see that you have a JSON object. If it is already in object form, there's no need for you to convert it at all. Just assign that JSON to a variable and pass that variable to your ajax `data` parameter like so:

```
$("#hexa-btn").on("click", function () {

    var json = { "index": 0, "x": 50, "y": 80, "weight": 2, "px": 50, "py": 80, "fixed": 0 };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/prototype/returndata", 
        data: json,
        success: function(data){
             console.log(data.index);
             console.log(data.x);
             console.log(data.y);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I am not sure to understand what you mean. Where do I do a conversion in my code ? And so, what do I have to write in the   `returndata()` function ?

Comment: no problem. I guess I thought you were running  `JSONshapes.shapes[0].nodes[0]` to convert some data into object form, where you said you have the JSON already there... in the `returndata()`, you can do whatever you like. What function do you want it to perform? so far, it is just grabbing the data sent from ajax

Comment: what is `JSONshapes.shapes[0].nodes[0]` this suppose to do?

Comment: JSONshapes.shapes[0].nodes[0] is my data in fact. It contains the node I want to push. My final goal would be to push the entire JSON object, but I would like first to try with one of them. No, my data is not already in the returndata() but in my JS file. Sorry if I was not clear about that.